# saving data to image in batch: need speedup

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to save a lot (say a million) images to disk, starting from data.
I'm able to achieve this using `matplotlib`, but the process is slow.
I profiled my script and found the bottlenecks are the lines:

- `ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])`
- `fig.clf()`

I have my data in a `numpy.array` of shape 56 x 56.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(num_events):
    image = create_camera_image(evts, i) # this gives me back the image in a numpy.array of shape 56 x 56

    fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
    fig.set_size_inches(1, 1)
    ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.]) # most expensive line
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    ax.imshow(image, filternorm=90, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap='hot')
    fig.savefig('filename'+str(i)+'.png', dpi=224)
    fig.clf() # second most expensive line
```

Is there a more performant way to do this?
I believe matplotlib **is not the best choice** to do this, but I can't use other libraries such as `pillow` or `opencv` to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for sure more efficient to create the figure, axes and image once and only update it with new data, instead of creating them all for each image.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_events = 10

def create_camera_image(i):
    return np.random.rand(56,56)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1,1),frameon=False)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_axis_off()

nullimage = np.zeros((56,56))
im = ax.imshow(nullimage, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', 
               cmap='hot', vmin=0,vmax=1)

for i in range(num_events):
    image = create_camera_image(i)
    im.set_data(image)

    fig.savefig('filename'+str(i)+'.png', dpi=224)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I'm only able to produce black images this way, as if the `null image` wouldn't be well replaced by `set_data`. Moreover, I have the white regions surrounding the camera image I didn't have before.

Comment: If you copy and paste the above code and run it, you get black images? It's working fine for me just as it should.

Comment: Your code works fine.
I guess the problem is in data, since your `create_camera_image` returns a (56, 56, 3) array, while mine a (56, 56).
I'll accept your answer back.
I'm investigating.

Comment: If you have a grey scale image, you need to normalize the imshowplot. I updated the answer to use a greyscale image.

Comment: This is an image I got from my original version:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhik8s9qu0tdp06/evt100_red.png?dl=0

And this is what I get now:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/18hi8kvuo6p03v3/evtnum500007_mcrunnum1400.png?dl=0

Quite good (not the same data but it's not relevant), but as you see I don't have camera contours now, nor a background color..

Comment: I added `im.set_norm(norm)`, defining `norm` such as: `norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)` where `vmin` and `vmax` are evaluated for each `image` and it's working fine.

But still I have white spaces around the image.

Comment: Given the information I have at my disposal I can in no way find out why you have white spaces around your image. The code above runs fine and gets rid of the whitespace. Also the code in the question does not produce white spaces. So you have something, which causes this, but how could I know what that is?

Comment: You can't, I was keeping you updated. Thx for your help!